# Best way to launch a child process in node that acts as a basic command shell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parent-child, ipc, child-process

I am attempting to spawn a child process in node wherein the process can operate as its own shell, essentially. For context, the idea is to run a child process inside of a repl. Here is what I have so far:

```
const args = path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "../fileBeingExecuted.js"));

const spawnOptions = { stdio: ["inherit", "inherit", "inherit", "ipc"] };

...(unrelated code)

spawn.on("close", () => {
   process.stdin.resume();
 });
```

It seems I am doing something wrong, because when the child process exits, the parent hangs instead of resuming its operation. More worrisome, `ctrl + d` closes both the child and the parent process whereas I would like it to only close the child.

Are there solutions I'm missing here?